# Bootstrap container-fluid on xs devices only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the full width on xs and sm devices (container-fluid) but just the container class for all other devices 
What's the best way to put this in place? 
I've tried jasnys bootstrap which has a container-smooth class but it doesn't centre the content when the screen gets over a certain size...

Comment: Have you noticed a need for this? `container` loses the "boxed" layout on `xs` devices naturally.

Comment: It doesn't quite use the full screen width on xs devices I've tested it, the container-fluid behaviour isn't seen on xs

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a custom `@media` query and customize the `.container` class.

Answer (score 12):

Overwrite the container class in your CSS and your done:

```
/* XS styling */
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
  .container {
    width: inherit;
  }
}

/* SM styling */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
  .container {
    width: inherit;
  }
}
```

Just replace the Less variables with your corresponding px-values.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do sth like this, and it works too:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .container {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For bootstrap 4.4 & onwards**

You can specify different `container` classes based on the device resolution. please have a look at the below example.

```
<div class="container-sm">
   /* Do your stuff here */
</div>
```

**For more customization**

[image]

**Reference:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: Just using the `container-md` class would work (`md` because they want 100% on both `xs` and `sm`). Using both classes will make one take priority over the other.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali  but in that case, you have to write custom CSS for padding. As container-fluid comes with its own feature so it's better to use which is the official recommendation.

Comment: You didn't understand my comment. I am saying you cannot use `container-sm` and `container-fluid` together. One will take precedence.
OP wants 100% on `xs` and `sm`, but default container on other screens. Even by the picture you uploaded from the docs `container-md` does exactly that.

Answer (score -4):

you can add a copy of the same container and configure it visible only in the sizes you want with the classes hidden-xx and visible-xx like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-md hidden-lg">
   your content here
</div>
```

and this for the normal container:

```
<div class="container hidden-xs hidden-sm">
       your content here
    </div>
```

Comment: you'd then need to duplicate your content though to accommodate both formats (ie xs, sm vs md, lg)

Comment: Unnecessary duplication of content.